# how to convert strings to float

Tags: tkinter, input, graph

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GB2U.png)

Hello, I am trying to write a code that takes in a number of inputs and outputs the graph that they form, (ex. quadratic equations, and cubic).
In the image linked I am trying to get in the inputs as entrys from a window that I have created using Tkinter, however, when I go to work with the values I need to convert them into float numbers, however, I don’t know how I can it.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read our [ask] page to find tips on how to improve this question.  Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here there is no function 'type' instead use 'delete' and 'insert'
the '0' represents the cursor position (i.e in starting)
and 'end' denotes till end

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk() 
def conversion():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    for i in (a,b,c,d):
        k=float(i.get())
        i.delete(0,'end')
        i.insert(0,k)
a=Entry(root,text='3')
a. pack() 
b=Entry(root)
b.pack() 
c=Entry(root)
c.pack() 
d=Entry(root)
d.pack() 
buttonl=Button(root, text="press",command=conversion)
buttonl.pack() 
root .mainloop()
```

Comment: if I want to use the values that I have converted into float, how can I do so? (how do I recall these values?)

Comment: @Balpreet couldn't get u ...but to get the values which are converted at last , just use `.get()` because `float()` converts only string and integers